# Is there a way to get outbound email working from with Apache and PHP on a Drobo 5N without compiling source code?

Tags: email, apache-http-server, php, smtp, drobo

I wanted to send emails from my web page running in Apache and PHP on my Drobo 5N. Found a lot of answers about cross-compiling MSTMP or SSTMP. For example the answers I found that specifically dealt with the Drobo were along the lines of:

1. Find a cross-compiler for your OS that can compile the source into something usable by the Drobo's operating system.
2. Download the source and all it's dependencies and then build the executable.
3. Create the scripts needed to install it into the Drobo's OS.
4. Package it all up into a tarball that can be placed in a specific directory in the Drobo file system.
5. Reboot the Drobo so that it will find the tarball and install the app.

While this all can be done, is there a simpler way to do this on the Drobo OS?

Comment: When you say “Found a lot of answers…” is there any way you can summarize the advice they give? This is a good answer but it is a bit “thin” for a self-answered question.

Comment: Perhaps I summarized a bit too much. Basically the answers I found that specifically dealt with the drobo were along the lines of: 1. find a cross-compiler for your OS that can compile the source into something usable by the Drobo's operating system. 2. Download the source and all it's dependencies and then build the executable. 3. Create the scripts needed to install it into the drobo's OS.  4. Package it all up into a tarball that can be placed in a specific directory in the drobo file system.  5. Reboot the drobo so that it will find the tarball and install the app.

Comment: I didn't think all that was necessary for someone like me who was looking for a quick and easy way to get email up and running on the Drobo 5N.

Comment: Look at my edit. Everything in your comment is now in the question and the question is more focused. This is all great work, but remember this is a question and answer site and having specifics as to why one method is better than another are always better than not having specifics. Good work on this solution!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get outbound email working on the Drobo 5N and it was a lot simpler than I thought it would be.

1. From the Drobo Dashboard, install the `Modoboa Mailserver` app. This app installs Postfix as a dependency.
2. Edit the file `DroboApps/apache/conf/php.ini` to add these 3 lines under the `[PHP]` section:

   ```
   sendmail_path="/mnt/DroboFS/Shares/DroboApps/mailserver/sbin/sendmail -t -i"  
   mail.add_x_header = On  
   mail.log = /mnt/DroboFS/Shares/DroboApps/apache/logs/mail.log
   ```
3. Back in the Drobo Dashboard, stop and restart Apache.  You're now good to go.

I created a simple PHP test script to test it.

```
<?php

    $to = "recipient@somewhere.com";
    $subj = "this is the subject";
    $message = "This is a test email";
    $headers = "From: sender@nowhere.net";

    mail($to, $subj, $message, $headers);
?>
```

And within seconds, I received the email.